# Error al intentar ejecurar el exe en ubuntu

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Tengo un problema con pyinstaller, yo seguí este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zPS8oQma4k, a la hora de ejecutar el exe me sale el siguiente error:

[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K1Pn.png)

Pd: Uso Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux no está desarrollado para correr archivos ejecutables (exe) de forma nativa. Si quieres puedes utilizar WineHQ para eso. Sigue las instrucciones en pantalla para instalarlo. Si el archivo instalador no se ejecuta, abre una "Ventana de Terminal" y escribe el directorio del archivo. Por ejemplo, "cd ~/Escritorio" seguido de "Wine fileinstall.exe", donde "fileinstall.exe" debe ser sustituido por el nombre del archivo.

Si quieres instrucciones de cómo hacelo, [aquí hay un manual](https://techlandia.com/ejecutar-archivos-exe-linux-como_42146/) paso a paso de como hacerlo.

Suerte!

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré

Comment: SI la respuesta te ha servido para aclarar, márcala así los demás visitantes que tengan la mismas dudas, podrán estar certero de la respuesta. Suerte!